# Show that the set $A=\{ n+m\sqrt{2}:n,m\in\mathbb{Z} \}$ is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that the set $A=\{ n+m\sqrt{2}:n,m\in\mathbb{Z} \}$ is countable.

My attempt:

Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable, its elements can be enumerated, and all elements in $A$ can be written as the following countable union:
\begin{eqnarray*}
A = \Big(\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigcup_{m=0}^{\infty} \{n+m\sqrt{2}\}\Big)\ \bigcup\ \Big(\bigcup_{n=0}^{-\infty}\bigcup_{m=0}^{-\infty}\{n+m\sqrt{2}\}\Big)
\end{eqnarray*}
Since countable unions of countable sets are countable, A must be countable.

Is this the right way to do it? Thank you

Edit: I know there is a better way now. But is my proof wrong?

Comment: Taking the bijection between $A$ and $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Okay would that be $f(\{n+m\sqrt{2}\})=(n,m)$?

Comment: Is my proof wrong?

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: Thank you! In that case I might like it better, because it saves me the step of proving that a function is injective

Answer (score 4):

Fairly simple
$\mathbb{Z}$ is countable, your set is $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{2}$, a bijection $\varphi(a+b\sqrt{2})=(a,b)$ is simple to prove and gives us $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{2}\to\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and we know the cartesian product of countable sets is countable, therefore it is countable.

Comment: Well written +1

Comment: Thanks. So my proof is wrong?

Comment: I really wish someone would answer this.

Comment: Besides notational error what you have done is essentially combining ordinary rpoof of integer countability and the cartesian one in a convuluted way which makes it more difficult to follow. The general idea from what I can see however is not wrong.

Comment: Okay. What notational error?

Comment: you don't write that n goes UP to $-\nfty$  but it is more commonly written it STARTS at negative infinity and then goes up to zero or whatever. I would say otherwise your general idea is correct but the issue lies in that it's more difficult to follow.

Comment: Thanks. So it would be written like $\bigcup_{n=-\infty}^{0}$?

Comment: Yes it would be written like that.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $~f:A\to\mathbb N,\quad f\Big(m+n\sqrt2\Big)~=~\begin{cases}2^a~3^b,~\quad&m\ge0,~n\ge0\\5^a~7^b,\quad&m\ge0,~n<0\\11^a~13^b,~\quad&m<0,~n\ge0\\17^a~19^b,\quad&m<0,~n<0\end{cases}\quad$

where $~a=|m|~$ and $~b=|n|$.